# Invalid token for decrypt function?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, python-cryptography

I've been using the cryptography.fernet python library to try to encrypt some string in a file, however every time I read from the file and try to decrypt it says I'm passing an invalid token into the decrypt function. I just need it to read from the file and decrypt it as read.

I already checked the variable type I'm passing into the function and it's a byte type variable. I already deleted and remade the file and I'm not sure why it says it's an invalid token.

```py
file = open(os.path.join("DATA", "pass"), 'r+b')
key = open(os.path.join("DATA", "key"), 'rb').read().rstrip()
crypt = Fernet(key)
read = file.read()
decrypt = self.crypt.decrypt(read)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 85, in decrypt
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

This is the exact error message I'm getting.

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: you need to use the same key that you used to write it. Here you are generating a new key and trying to decrypt your file with the new key. Instead you need to genearte your Fernet object using the original key you used to encypt the data

Comment: `Invalidtoken` is raised when the ciphertext is in some way faulty - https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#cryptography.fernet.Fernet.decrypt - see the raises section

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the same key which you encrypted the data with Here you are generating a new key and trying to use that to decrypt the data which you previously encrypted with a different key. In the code example below. you can see i have generated 2 keys. I encrypt the data with the first key and i can succesfully decrpyt it with the first key. However if i try to decyrpt with the second key i get invalid token error since this is not the key i used to encrypt the data

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet


def my_encrypt(key, data):
    f = Fernet(key)
    return f.encrypt(data)


def my_decrypt(key, data):
    f = Fernet(key)
    return f.decrypt(data)


my_key = Fernet.generate_key()
other_key = Fernet.generate_key()
my_string = b"my deep dark secret"
print(my_string)
my_encrypt_string = my_encrypt(my_key, my_string)
print(my_encrypt_string)
my_decrypt_string = my_decrypt(my_key, my_encrypt_string)
print(my_decrypt_string)
other_decrypt_string = my_decrypt(other_key, my_encrypt_string)
```

OUTPUT

```
b'my deep dark secret'
b'gAAAAABdSoKHUm4xCGDZ1JYneogK62U_GQnluw-ekn8xRi0rT8_9FzK0iMY41pksCg5OpPgoD0pJlJFsGF4WjIMeMWVpPdkQklL2JjQbbEhfcx6Qpazm_eA='
b'my deep dark secret'


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cd00119621\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 106, in _verify_signature
    h.verify(data[-32:])
  File "C:\Users\cd00119621\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hmac.py", line 69, in verify
    ctx.verify(signature)
  File "C:\Users\cd00119621\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\hmac.py", line 73, in verify
    raise InvalidSignature("Signature did not match digest.")
cryptography.exceptions.InvalidSignature: Signature did not match digest.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cd00119621/PycharmProjects/ideas/stackoverflow.py", line 22, in <module>
    other_decrypt_string = my_decrypt(other_key, my_encrypt_string)
  File "C:/Users/cd00119621/PycharmProjects/ideas/stackoverflow.py", line 11, in my_decrypt
    return f.decrypt(data)
  File "C:\Users\cd00119621\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 75, in decrypt
    return self._decrypt_data(data, timestamp, ttl)
  File "C:\Users\cd00119621\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 119, in _decrypt_data
    self._verify_signature(data)
  File "C:\Users\cd00119621\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 108, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

So when you encypt the data you need to store the key you used to encrypt it as you will need to use that same key to decrypt it

Comment: Sorry, you're right. However, I had written the code on stack overflow wrong. What it actually does is read the key from a file and use it as the decrypt key.

Comment: So is this problem fixed? If not, `InvalidToken` is raised when the ciphertext has been tampered with - it requires part of the ciphertext to decrypt, because the ciphertext is in reality the (encrypted message, a timestamp, the IV) and a HMAC of the other joined parts.